# Don't get post with <button> tag via bootstrap

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I usually used input tag in my form:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="pass">
```

And I got `$_POST[pass]` after press button.

Starting use *Bootstrap 3* example form with:

```
<button type="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```

I got empty `$_POST`

Comment: Is the button placed inside the form? Show us the surrounding code too, please.

Comment: What browser? In which context `<button>` is used? Show us a bit more.

Comment: Yes, button in form. Chrome. When i change on <input type="submit" name="pass" class="btn btn-success"> it work.

Comment: Using `$_POST[pass]` is completely different from using `$_POST['pass']`. The first uses a `constant` (which probably doesn't exist), the other uses a string literal as key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an input element, the value attribute serves as the label and the data that will be submitted. With a button, the child nodes of the element become the label but **the value attribute still determines the value**.

A form control needs a value **and** a name to be successful (i.e. appear in submitted data), since **you don't have a value**, you won't get any data submitted from the button.

Add a value.

```
<button type="submit" 
        name="pass"
        value="some value"
        class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
```